# Show that the function $w=g(z)=e^{z^2}$ maps the lines $x=y$ and $x=-y$ onto the circle $|w| =1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I'm working through the book Complex Variables by S.D. Fisher. This is one of the exercises from chapter 1. The question also asked me to show further that $g$ maps each of the two pieces of the region $\{x + iy: x^2 > y^2\}$ onto the set $\{w: |w| > 1\}$ and each of the two pieces of the region $\{x + iy: x^2 < y^2\}$ onto the set $\{w: |w|<1\}$.

Here is my approach: Since complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}$ can be represented as $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$, and $z=x+iy$. We have $e^{z^2}=e^{(x+iy)^2}=e^{x^2-y^2+i2xy}=e^{x^2-y^2}e^{i2xy}=|w|e^{i\theta}$. Then can I say $|w|=e^{x^2-y^2}$? Or does this path work at all? What can I do instead?

Comment: $e^{x^2-y^2}e^{i2xy}=|w|e^{i\theta}$ implies that $e^{x^2-y^2}=|w|$ by just taking modulus on both sides. Polar decomposition is unque for non-zero complex numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\because w & =g(z)=e^{z^2}=e^{(x \pm x i)^2}=e^{x^2 \pm 2 x^2 i-x^2} \\
& =e^{\pm 2 x^2 i}=\cos \left(2 x^2\right) \pm i \sin \left(2 x^2\right) \\
\therefore & |w|=\cos ^2\left(2 x^2\right)+\sin ^2\left(2 x^2\right)=1
\end{aligned}
$$
For surjectivity, in order to map any $w=e^{\theta i}$, we have $z=e^{\pm \frac{\sqrt{|\theta|}}{2}}$ such that $g(z)=w$.

Comment: This is not so su**b**jective to me, but rather su**r**jective

Comment: Auto correct my ‘surjectivity’ subjectively.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the right approach. Notice that on those pair of lines, we have $x^2=y^2$ so that $w(x,y)=e^{2ixy}$. The map $w: \big\{(x,y): x^2=y^2 \big\}\to\big\{z: |z|=1\big\}, (x,y)\mapsto e^{2ixy}$ is clearly surjective so that the entire unit circle is covered (many times over in fact, meaning that the map is also not injective)

Answer (score 0):

We can parameterize these lines as $z=t\pm ti$ and note that $z^2=\pm 2ti$ so this is just $f(z)=e^{\pm 2ti}$ which is the unit circle.